Hyperref and NiceMatrix Question
I was making a template for 30-question test solutions that has a navigation box to each question, however I am hoping to make it more user-friendly as a template. Essentially, I was wondering if you could help me clean up this code to do so.
In each solution box, there is a generated hyperlink based on a counter. I was wondering for the navigation box, if one could use NiceMatrix's \CodeBefore to make every cell have the hyperlink code applied to the number so users could just input just the answers without the clutter.
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark, nicematrix, makecell}

\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}
\newcolumntype{-}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}
\definecolor{Blue4}{HTML}{1d5c9d}
\begin{document}
\begin{center} \def\arraystretch{1}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{-c|c?c|c?c|c-} 
    \Xhline{3\arrayrulewidth}
       \hyperlink{Q1}{\textcolor{Blue4}{1}} &  D   & \hyperlink{Q11}{\textcolor{Blue4}{11}}& B   & \hyperlink{Q21}{\textcolor{Blue4}{21}}&  A  \\ \hline
        \hyperlink{Q2}{\textcolor{Blue4}{2}} &  E   & \hyperlink{Q12}{\textcolor{Blue4}{12}}& B  & \hyperlink{Q22}{\textcolor{Blue4}{22}}&  A  \\ \hline
        \hyperlink{Q3}{\textcolor{Blue4}{3}}&  C   & \hyperlink{Q13}{\textcolor{Blue4}{13}}& A  & \hyperlink{Q23}{\textcolor{Blue4}{23}}&  D  \\ \hline
        \hyperlink{Q4}{\textcolor{Blue4}{4}}&  D   & \hyperlink{Q14}{\textcolor{Blue4}{14}}& B  & \hyperlink{Q24}{\textcolor{Blue4}{24}}&  C  \\ \hline
        \hyperlink{Q5}{\textcolor{Blue4}{5}}&  D   & \hyperlink{Q15}{\textcolor{Blue4}{15}}& C  & \hyperlink{Q25}{\textcolor{Blue4}{25}}&  A \\  \Xhline{5\arrayrulewidth}
        \hyperlink{Q6}{\textcolor{Blue4}{6}}&  D   & \hyperlink{Q16}{\textcolor{Blue4}{16}}& B  & \hyperlink{Q26}{\textcolor{Blue4}{26}}&  D  \\ \hline 
        \hyperlink{Q7}{\textcolor{Blue4}{7}}&  C   & \hyperlink{Q17}{\textcolor{Blue4}{17}}& C  & \hyperlink{Q27}{\textcolor{Blue4}{27}}&  A  \\ \hline
        \hyperlink{Q8}{\textcolor{Blue4}{8}}&  C   & \hyperlink{Q18}{\textcolor{Blue4}{18}}& B  & \hyperlink{Q28}{\textcolor{Blue4}{28}}&  D  \\ \hline
        \hyperlink{Q9}{\textcolor{Blue4}{9}}&  B   & \hyperlink{Q19}{\textcolor{Blue4}{19}}& B & \hyperlink{Q29}{\textcolor{Blue4}{29}}&  C  \\ \hline
        \hyperlink{Q10}{\textcolor{Blue4}{10}}& C   & \hyperlink{Q20}{\textcolor{Blue4}{29}}& C  & \hyperlink{Q30}{\textcolor{Blue4}{30}}& B   \\ \Xhline{3\arrayrulewidth}
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}

Thanks so much.

\begin{document} is missing

Thanks! It has been edited.

You could use the tabularray package:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Blue4}{HTML}{1d5c9d}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\newcounter{foo}

\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
    \begin{tblr}{
      hlines,
      hline{1,6,11}={1.2pt},
      vlines,
      vline{1,3,5,7}={1.2pt},
      colspec={cccccc},
      cell{1-Z}{odd}={
        cmd={%
          \setcounter{foo}{\numexpr(\thecolnum-1)*5+\therownum}%
          \hyperlink{Q\thefoo}{\arabic{foo}}%
        },
        fg=Blue4
      }
    } 
       & D && B && A\\ 
       & D && B && A\\        
       & D && B && A\\ 
       & D && B && A\\        
       & D && B && A\\ 
       & D && B && A\\        
       & D && B && A\\ 
       & D && B && A\\        
       & D && B && A\\ 
       & D && B && A\\        
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\newpage

\hypertarget{Q1}{Text 1}

\newpage

\hypertarget{Q30}{Text 30}
\end{document}



With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Blue4}{HTML}{1d5c9d}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{center} 

\newcolumntype{A}
  {>{\color{Blue4}\hyperlink{Q\inteval{\value{iRow}}}{\inteval{\value{iRow}}}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}
  {>{\color{Blue4}\hyperlink{Q\inteval{\value{iRow}+10}}{\inteval{\value{iRow}+10}}}c}
\newcolumntype{C}
  {>{\color{Blue4}\hyperlink{Q\inteval{\value{iRow}+20}}{\inteval{\value{iRow}+20}}}c}


\begin{NiceTabular}{AcBcCc}[hvlines]
& D && B && A\\ 
& D && B && A\\        
& D && B && A\\ 
& D && B && A\\        
& D && B && A\\ 
& D && B && A\\        
& D && B && A\\ 
& D && B && A\\        
& D && B && A\\ 
& D && B && A\\        
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [very thick] 
    \draw (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) ; 
    \draw (1-|3) -- (last-|3) ; 
    \draw (1-|5) -- (last-|5) ; 
    \draw (6-|1) -- (6-|last) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{center}


\newpage

\hypertarget{Q1}{Text 1}

\newpage

\hypertarget{Q30}{Text 30}


\end{document}


